# First Boost async_read isn't invoked

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

There is a [server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp) and [client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/client.cpp) SSL example on boost.org. I've changed the client so that it will invoke an `async_read` first and then send a request with `async_write`. The server is in listen mode (`async_read`) at first, so it will get the request and send it to the client, but I don't get the result in the client.

I really am confused about how `async_read` and `async_write` are invoked behind the scene. For example, if `async_read` is called first, does it wait behind for receiving data or it will be dequeued after `async_write` invoked (because no data received)? If it's not, why do I need a second or third `async_read` to get reply of first `async_write` from server (as you seen in the results below)?

Please see the [changes to original file](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/compare/develop...pnxtm:patch-2) that makes client read-first.

This is the results when client connected and send data to server:

```html
Verifying /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
Enter message: 1234567890
Enter message: aaaaaaaaaa
Enter message: bbbbbbbbbb
Reply: 1234567890
Enter message: cccccccccc
Reply: aaaaaaaaaa
Enter message: dddddddddd
Reply: bbbbbbbbbb
Enter message:
```

**Edit:**
I've checked more situations and get new results. I've changed the code so that in the completion function of `async_write` the `send_request()` method didn't run again (so we won't get new data from user to send). Please see the changes in [this patch](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/compare/develop...pnxtm:pnxtm-patch-3). 
The results is as follow:

```html
1 Verifying /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
2 Enter message: 1234567890
3 Reply: 1234567890
4 Read failed: stream truncated          <--- Server closed at this point
```

At line 4 there is a waiting read and as you can see `async_read` lambda invoked and displayed the error result(because server is closed manually). So far, I've realized that the second `async_write` (one that is called in the result of invoked lambda) makes first `async_read` dequeued (or something similar).